# Changing the Keyboard for Specific App on Android

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, multilingual

I am developing a "Nepali Dictionary Android App" using Cordova. Using `jQuery` I have been able to map the keyboard character to [Devnagari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari).  For example If you pressed the 'k' from keyboard 'क' will be displayed in editable text inputs. Now , I am trying to change the keyboard characters so that the users could see Nepali characters in keyboard.

I don't know If it is possible or not, but I think it should be. I am not a `java` programmer and using `cordova` api to build the android applications. I am also planning to create `MultiKeyboard` Phonegap / Cordova Plugin for android (in future ) if It is possible.

My Question is :
**How can I change the android keyboard characters for some specific apps ?**

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED**

I have not started coding for this because I don't know if it is possible or not. Please show me the right way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could change char value with different value if the given input values will not be used. What i mean is if 'k' will never be used you could catch that input in for example

```
var tempChar;
```

variable and swap it's value from a HashMap, but I don't know if you can change the layout of keyboard using PhoneGap only. If you can't do, you can draw your own keyboard using jQuery Mobile if there is way to disable Android keyboard for your app.

Comment: If `java` could do the magic I am ready for that. `you can draw your own keyboard using jQuery Mobile if there is way to disable Android keyboard for your app` is appreciable. But I am also unknown to that. Thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: There are few topics on disabling and hiding Android Keyboard but for native apps, I don't know if PhoneGap has a method to call a native method or API for these kind of trick. I didn't use it for 1.5 years. But what I don't understand is isn't there Nepali (or what its called, sorry) language option for Android keyboard that you can force change it.

Comment: Yes ,there are some on google play (but not sure), but if there is one it should be installed separately. I want the keyboard to be built-in in my app.

Comment: I know that, what i mean is if this language is come with Anroid that can be selected in Setting as your locale. If it is you can change locale then return to original locale after application closed but I don't really recommend that.

Comment: What are `Key Character Map Files` `.kcm` files? Do you think I should give a glance to it for solving this. Thank you for showing me 3 more alternative ways. Upvoted your answer for its good logic :)

Comment: That is to deep for an app. This files (and that document) are for developers that build Android/ROM for a device. These files can not be changed without root access and AFAIK need a restart to make affect.

Comment: Oh, then I will go with your answer or your first comment after some research on both. If you have some useful links to start with any of them please provide me.